# Plural of input

Tags: grammar, nouns, grammatical-number, word-usage

What is the plural of input ?

It proves unclear which is correct, input or inputs --- or both up to context of usage.

Comment: In programming, I use inputs or input fields

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it depends.

When the word input is used as a countable item, such as requirements in a software, inputs designates the plurality of the same.

However, when an input is used as a generic uncountable noun, such as helpful input from your superiors, or such, the uncountable form is the one that needs to be used.

Comment: One of the criteria for discriminating countable from mass nouns is the existence of a plural form: if and when a noun is used in a mass sense, it admits of no plural. Try typing "electricities" in any software with spell-check turned on.

Comment: I agree, the cause and effect relationship has to be nailed down, however; @BrianDonovan.